# Can an app get a permission to a whole sub tree from SAF?

Tags: android, uri, android-permissions, android-contentresolver

Can a third party app request a Storage provider through [Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) to grant it with premissions to delete files within\copy files to a directory or in any subtree underneath the tree `Uri` recieved `onActivityResult` by a call to `startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE),14)`?

If it can, how do you claim it on the third party app code?

I tried

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but when i try to delete a file in the subtree i get :

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0403-0201%3ADCIM%2Fthai2%2FDSC_0024.JPG from pid=26781, uid=10749 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

EDIT : To explain my use case and maybe get other suggestions for it, I am developing an app that helps users manage photos they have on their device, if its by helping arrange them in albums or delete them fast and easy. That means that without premissions to manage files in the SD card it becomes almost useless (at least for me, as i got SD of 64gb with a nice amount of photos and barely 1gb free on the internal storage, and i am the most active user of this app i believe lol).

Comment: Note that the Storage Access Framework does not itself grant anything with respect to permissions. Storage providers grant permissions; the Storage Access Framework provides clients with an API to take those permissions. So even if this is possible, you might not get it for any given provider. That being said, I have not played with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` much, let alone your scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare Right, thanks for the clearification i will edit my question accordingly

Comment: @OfekRon Did you get a solution for the above?