# Is it possible to write on portable mounted SDcard? (Android 6 marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

I can read contents of sd card but I cannot make change to them.
I have added `android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`
to manifest and also implemented runtime permission in app.

(I'm using judiotagger to edit mp3 files tag. It has no problem with files in internal storage but when editing files on sd card throws CannotWriteException like this: Cannot make changes to file /storage/DED3-1EF9/Music/abc.mp3)

I have read almost all of related topics but non of them helped me.

ps: I khow we can do it in application specific directory on sd card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to write on portable mounted SDcard?

Not via `File`, `FileOutputStream`, and related file-specific classes.

You are welcome to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+, allowing the user to choose the content to work with via the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). You can use the `Uri` that you get back to get an `InputStream` and, later, an `OutputStream` to use to read and write the content.

Comment: Sorry if im out of place but maybe you can answer, How could this be that such a basic and mandatory API, that would simply let a user grant a third party app with premission to manage (delete,edit,create) files on the SD card in as easy way as it is to mange files in device's storage just doesnt exists untill now, from API 19 to 24. Thats just frustrates me as a developer and as an Android user. Why would they not expose such API?

Comment: Note that i dont count SAF as such API cause it's not simple at all compared to regular java File APIs, and also so strict that its almost impossible to work with if you need premissions to a lot of files in diffrent places on the SD card... True there is action_open_document_tree but i couldnt seem to make it work and there is little documentation about it... (even you couldnt help me with this... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468298/can-an-app-get-a-permission-to-a-whole-sub-tree-from-saf)

Comment: @OfekRon: "Why would they not expose such API?" -- asking "why did Developer X do Thing Y?" on Stack Overflow is not productive. Usually, the only person who can provide a conclusive answer is Developer X, and Developer X is unlikely to see your question. The key behind the Storage Access Framework is that it supports much more than just bare files (Google Drive/Dropbox/other cloud providers, custom encrypted containers, and so on).

Comment: `Dropbox`. @CommonsWare Dropbox still does not support saf. Just installed the latest Dropbox app on Marshmellow 6.0. Or should i do something else?

Comment: @greenapps: That's odd. I thought I heard that they implemented a storage provider. They should. The whole [storage provider API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#custom) is open and is specifically designed with Dropbox sorts of scenarios in mind.

Comment: @CommonsWare I selected the sd card root as document tree but still it won't give me the permission to edit files on sd card using `OutputStream`. I am using absolute path of mp3 files for `OutputStream` is it wrong?

Comment: @MRM: I hope that's wrong, otherwise we have a security problem in Android. You should need to go through the storage provider, via an appropriate `Uri`, rather than directly via the filesystem.

Comment: What do you mean by appropriate Uri? What kind of Uri should be used?

Comment: @MRM: A `Uri` provided by a storage provider. "I selected the sd card root as document tree" -- this gave you an appropriate `Uri`, representing that particular collection of documents. Using `DocumentFile`, you can attempt to traverse that collection, getting appropriate `Uri` values for any documents or nested trees.

Comment: So I should search the Uri provided by MediaStore in tree Uri? How can I do that?

Comment: @MRM: You already get a valid `Uri` from the `MediaStore`. You need to assemble it from the `_ID` value using `ContentUris`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v7.6/RecyclerView/VideoList/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/RowController.java#L56-L59

Comment: @CommonsWare Google Drive  does not support -is not contained in- ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Only ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. So one can pick only files. Not directories. I wonder why they did not implement that.

Comment: @CommmonsWare Dropbox does support ACTION_GET_CONTENT. But only very primitive: it first downloads a file to a cache on file system. After that you get an uri for the cached file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried `ContentUris.withAppendedId` for `OutputStream` as you said, but it throws `SecurityException: Neither user nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I also checked it with `DocumentFile.isDocumentUri` and it returns false!